# Clarification on Joins - SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on my project where I had to SQL in it. And I ran into a problem as I am not getting the expected results from the query I used. I am still learning my experience in SQL so any help here would be super helpful. Problem is narrated as follows:

Query Used:

```
select count(distinct del_table.user_id) as distinct_user_id,
       count(1) as row_counts
from user_names del_table join
     userids req
     on req.user_id = del_table.user_id;
```

Table `user_name`

[image: user_name column values]

Table `userids`

[image]

From the above query, I am expecting results as below

[image: expected result]

but I am getting like below

[image: returned result]

Basically, the `row_counts` gets doubled and not sure why. Can someone help me point the mistake I am making and help correct my query to achieve my expected results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

For the data you have provided, you should get the results that you expect.  In other words, your understanding is correct.

To debug this problem, count the number of rows in each table.  In this case, you know that `12345` is the only match, so we can limit the counts to that:

```
select count(*)
from user_names
where user_id = 12345

select count(*)
from userids
where user_id = 12345;
```

I would guess that these return either `1`/`6` or `2`/`3`.  In other words, the tables don't contain what you think they contain.

Comment: I just noticed that in table ```userids``` the value ```12345``` is present couple of times. That has caused the ```row_counts``` to be doubled?

Comment: @user3624000 . . . Yes.  The number of rows generated for 12345 is the product of the number of rows in each table.

Comment: "a couple of times"? I'd suspect twice. Yes that would have the row counts doubled, because each row of the `user_names` table is joined with each matching row from the `user_ids` table.

Comment: Got it. Thank you both.